# Getting Alexa CategoryListings by Country

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

From what I've understood about Alexa's CategoryListings action ( see [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/index.html) for more info ( check API Reference/Actions/CategoryListings )), Alexa basically scrapes [DMOZ](http://www.dmoz.org/)
 for websites in specific categories and then checks the ranking in it's database ( if you choose to sorty by 'Popularity' ).

This makes sense to me and works fine, but two questions arise:

1. Does Alexa support ordering by Popularity but Country-specific ( e.g. [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) ranks 56 in the world, but 13 in India )
2. If it doesn't, why? I mean, if my assumptions that they have to scrape DMOZ is correct, it doesn't seem like too much to add country ranking as well. I could, of course, get the global rank of some category sites and then query each site for specific country but I'd have to pay additionally for that. Is the reason behind this financial or technical?

I currently need the answer to only the first question, since it's essential to the thing I'm doing. The second question is out of sheer curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my question:
No, this is not possible (at least to this date) to do this. What I did was get the list of global sites by popularity and then filtered out top 1000 by querying each of them and getting it's rank in a specific country.